# Visual studio C++ - create the new project with settings from existing project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

can anyone recommend the way to create the new project in Visual Studio C++ with all the settings (flags and switches) like in another project?

let say i have a project with settings for releases: debug, release and release statist - all for Win32 and Win64. If i create a new project i have only debug and release for Win32 - how to copy target definitions - so it will be identical between two projects?

Visual Studio 2010/2017

Adam

Comment: This is what Property Sheets are for.  Read up on those.

Comment: You can try Menu -> Project -> Export Template, and then use the newly created template to create your new project.

Comment: i do know property sheet for the project - i would like to avoid switching page by page and copying every line - looking for some instruction what to copy from which file - or how to export this part and import to another file. I have noticed that almost all property pages are hold withing the vcproj file. and optional user properties.

Comment: The idea with creating the template is quite interesting.